# how to deliver keyboard input by powershell code?

Tags: powershell, keyboard, mouse

The following ps code runs correctly, on Win10

```
#import mouse_event
Add-Type -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int info);' -Name U32 -Namespace W1;
#left mouse click
[W1.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);
#move 10% along x and 10% along y and send left mouse click
[W1.U32]::mouse_event(0x02 -bor 0x04 -bor 0x8000 -bor 0x01, .1*65535, .5 *65535, 0, 0);
```

which moves the mouse cursor to a specified position and make it do a left click.

However, when I test the keybd_event function supposed to be included inside user32.dll, I run into an error, saying "user32.dll" does not contain such function.

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);' -Name U33 -Namespace W1;
#left mouse click
[W1.U33]::keybd_event(0x31, 0x02, 0, 0);
```

Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: the usual way to automate UI interaction is with AutoIT, AutoHotKey, or [with web pages] Selenium. the 1st and 3rd of those have PoSh modules that seem to be well thot of. [*grin*]

Comment: Your sample works for me. What version of windows are you on?

Comment: I use windows 10 professional.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, thanks. The softwares you recommend are alternatives to solve my problem. I will look into them. Best.

Comment: @yychen - you are welcome ... and i wish you the very best of good luck! [*grin*]